# get list on bases of input parameter

Tags: java, list, generics, collections

I have the below method in Java:

```
public <T> List<?> getList(String str, Class<T> clazz ){
    List<T> lst = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] arr = str.split(",");
    for(String s : arr){
        lst.add(clazz.cast(s));
    }
    return lst;
}
```

I want the output of this method like this:

```
List<Integer> lst = getList("1,2",Integer.class)

List<String> lst = getList("ab,cfv",String.class)
...
...
etc
```

But the problem here is when I am passing "`1,2`" and `Integer.class`, I am getting `classCastException` at "`clazz.cast(s)`"

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You are not guaranteed that `String s` can be cast to type`T`. How would `List<Socket> sockets  = getList("asdf", Socket.class);` work?

Comment: Thanks .. for string, it is working

Comment: Not surprising. You can cast a `String` to a `String` with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is related to the fact that you try to cast a `String` into an `Integer` which cannot work since `String` is not a sub class of `Integer`, you should provide a [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) that will convert your `String` into the target type instead as next:

```
public <T> List<T> getList(String str, Function<String, T> parser){
    return Arrays.stream(str.split(",")).map(parser).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

*Example:*

```
List<Integer> lst = getList("1,2", Integer::valueOf);
System.out.println(lst);
```

*Output:*

```
[1, 2]
```

---

The previous code works with **Java 8** and above, for previous versions, the logic is the same, you simply need to use [`FluentIterable`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html) from **Google Guava** to replace the `Stream` and use [`com.google.common.base.Function`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Function.html) instead of `java.util.function.Function` the result is the following:

```
public <T> List<T> getList(String str, Function<String, T> parser){
    return FluentIterable.from(Arrays.asList(str.split(","))).transform(parser).toList();
}
```

*Example:*

```
List<Integer> lst = getList(
    "1,2",
    new Function<String, Integer>() {
        public Integer apply(final String input) {
            return Integer.valueOf(input);
        }
    }
);
```

*Output:*

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Integer and string are not in the same hierarchy. They both derive from object but branch different ways. You could do as the other answer says or change the parameter String to Object.

```
      Object
     /      \
    /        \
String     Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create `ICaster` interface:

```
public interface ICaster<T> {
    T cast(String a);
}
```

and its implementations e.g:

```
public class IntegerCaster implements ICaster<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer cast(String a) {
        return Integer.parseInt(a);
    }
}
```

Then instead of `Class<T> clazz` parameter in `getList` method, you should use `ICaster<T> caster`.

Here is new `getList` method:

```
public static <T> List<?> getList(String str, ICaster<T> caster){

    List<T> lst = new ArrayList<>();

    String[] arr = str.split(",");
    for(String s : arr){
        lst.add(caster.cast(s));
    }

    return lst;
}
```

And usage example:

```
List<Integer> lst = (List<Integer>) getList("1,2",new IntegerCaster());
```

The output should be: `[1, 2]`